# Strangely no NODE_MODULES folder is created running npm install and there is no warnings

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am learning React and now I am trying this [GitHub quarentineBoredom](https://github.com/luzma87/quarentineBoredom).

It looks all normal, there's nothing strange in package.json or other special files, but when I run `npm install` in the dir where package.json is in no node_modules folder is created.

I read many posts about this and can't find a solution. What can I try next?

packages.json

```
{
  "name": "quarentine-boredom",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.27",
    "@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "big-human-readable-ids": "^2.0.1",
    "d3": "^5.15.0",
    "firebase": "^7.12.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Terminal Output:

[image]

Comment: This project probably uses yarn as dependency manager. Could you [install yarn](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#windows-stable) on your system and try `yarn install`

Comment: Will the yarn be installed in all project or only in this? I'm afraid I mess up my NPM installation

Comment: yarn will be a global installation in your system like npm. It shouldn't be interfering with npm. It will be available on the command line as a separate command. 

If you do  `yarn install` inside your project, then it will install the dependencies for you only in this project.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `npm install` do you see any errors? It's likely that there's an issue with one (or more) of the packages, and/or your npm version is out of date.

Comment: Thanks, I added Terminal output in my question!